# POST request with List of MultipartFile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to perform POST request with Multipart Form Data. I have this controller receiving request

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/photos", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @Operation(summary = "Accepts photo. Adds photo to queue for sending to Telegram chat")
    private void sendPhotos(@RequestPart List<MultipartFile> photos,
                            @RequestParam long cityId,
                            @RequestParam(required = false) String caption) {
       sendToCityChatUseCase.execute(photos, cityId, caption);
    }
```

I'm using RestTemplate to send List of MultipartFile:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
MultiValueMap<String, Object> files = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
for (MultipartFile file : photos) {
    files.add("photos", file);
}
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(files, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(chatBotUrl, requestEntity,String.class);
```

When I use such implementation I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.FileDescriptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
```

When I've changed `files.add("photos", file);` to `files.add("photos", file.getBytes());` I've managed to perform request but got `MissingServletRequestPartException` because there wasn't `photos` part in that request.

I think I'm missing something. Have no pleasure writing new converter myself and hope there is other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your types are not matching you should change your client to:

```
MultiValueMap<String, List<MultipartFile>> files = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
List<byte[]> photosByteArray = photos.stream().map(photo -> {
      try {
        return photo.getBytes();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
files.add("photos", photosByteArray); //No loop here since server expects list
```

And you might want to add `spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false` in your properties file

Comment: Added this and still have an exception.

Comment: UPD: Added ObjectMapper bean with `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` disabled. Still get serialization exception somehow

Comment: Is it the same exception?

Comment: Yep. Totally same

Comment: What is the error when you change to getByte? I guess it can't be the same one then...

Comment: Hello. Sorry for long time waiting. I had incorrect boundaries error. Probably because of one of converters. I've tried to reproduce it and got no errors. Please can you write another post with that solution? I'll mark it as answer in case someone face this problem too

Comment: Updated this one with byte array